# replace multiple values in data.table with R

Tags: r, for-loop, replace, data.table

I have tried multiple ways to replace two values in a data table with NA.

The data are [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deborah-Jia/Complete_Analysis_da2/main/eg1.csv). There are two values `9223372036854775807` and `2147483647` which I intend to replace with `NA`

```
library(data.table)

data <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deborah-Jia/Complete_Analysis_da2/main/eg1.csv", integer64 = "numeric")
```

I tried:

```
data[data = 9223372036854775807|2147483647]
```

had error:

> Error in `[.data.table`(data, , data = 9223372036854775808 | 2147483647,  :
> unused argument (data = 9223372036854775808 | 2147483647)

I checked the structure of [i, j, by...] but couldn't find the cause. So, I use for loop instead:

```
# only these cols have 9223372036854775807 and 2147483647
special_col <- data %>% select(matches("price|size|room")) %>% colnames()

for ( icol in special_col) {
  data[icol == 9223372036854775807|2147483647, icol := NA] 
}
```

It didn't work as expected; I can still find `2147483647` in the data table.

I know I can use

```
data[total_room_count_high == 9223372036854775807|2147483647, total_room_count_high := NA]
```

and replicate each column, but it is rather tiresome.

Before these methods, I also did `across`, `filter_at` and `mapply` combined with a `function` to process each column. But as long as I put `col` inside `data[ ]`, then data.table would think `col` is a column name rather than a variable representing all columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For comparison you should use `==`. You can use `|` as -

```
data <- read.csv2("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deborah-Jia/Complete_Analysis_da2/main/eg1.csv")
data[data == 2147483647 | data == 9223372036854775807] <- NA
data
```

Answer (score 0):

an approach using `set`

```
values <- c(9223372036854775807, 2147483647)
for(col in names(data)) set(data, i = which(data[[col]] %in% values), j = col, value = NA_integer_)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `9223372036854775807` is not "really" in your data but is the way that integer64 sometimes represent NAs.

You can just replace the integer columns.

```r
data <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deborah-Jia/Complete_Analysis_da2/main/eg1.csv", integer64 = "numeric")
for (j in seq_along(data)) {
  vj <- .subset2(data, j)
  if (is.integer(vj)) {
    i <- which(vj == .Machine$integer.max)
    set(data, i = i, j = j, value = NA_integer_)
  }
}
```

Note that `2147483647` might be there to represent "positive infinity" using integers and so might be a better representation than `NA`. (For example, if you want to filter on all properties above a certain price, these properties will be erroneously filtered if you replace these values with `NA`).